# How to 'set timezone' for psql from jpa entitymanager?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, timezone, psql

How should I manipulate timestamp in UTC to be able to append offset?

I know the basics from here:
http://blog.untrod.com/2016/08/actually-understanding-timezones-in-postgresql.html

But yet to find a proper solution for this problem:

Psql  database is in UTC, for a date stored in db I want to pass the zone and get back the correct timezone result:
say passing Europe/Berlin should result in : 2018-02-03 02:00:00+00 -> 2018-02-03 04:00:00+02:00

When I use `select my_date with time zone 'Europe/Berlin'` will increment the hour correctly but unfortanetly will truncate the offset.
One solution I have found is 'set timezone=Europe/Berlin' before the query which works like a charm when I use
it from pure sql. However when I try to invoke it as nativequery it results in error, maybe because it isnt a DML query.

I have tried to set the session's timezone from java code for a session :

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().withOptions()
.jdbcTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"))
.openSession();
```

But a query in the same session ( `SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');`) says it is still UTC.

I can overcome this problem from code(transforming result from java code according to the zone), however I want to do it from 
sql query.

Is that possible somehow?